# Build intro, read App local settings

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

I'm totally new with react-native and trying to build my first app.

Problem is that I would to like make Intro for App and I have decided to use react-native-app-intro for that. Once the user has passed the application intro I will change firstRun state to false in Redux store. For persistent saving settings to device I use redux-persist.

I just don't get it how I can skip intro next time. For navigation I am using react-navigation. I have made if statement to intro scene

```
// Intro
...
render(){
if (this.props.settings.firstRun === false){
   this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
}
...
```

this works, but is there better way to do this. Because of redux store initialization app will always get my initial settings for firstRun: true.

```
// my settings reducer   
export default function(state = settingsInitState, action) {
switch(action.type){
    case 'SETTINGS_CHANGE':
        state.firstRun = action.payload.value;
        return state;
        break;
}
return state;
}

const settingsInitState = {
        firstRun: true,
};
// actions
export const changeSettings = (settings) => {
return {
    type: settings.type,
    payload: settings
}
}
```

Should I skip somehow @@redux/INIT and @@redux/PROBE states in reducer settings initialization.

Can someone point some example how to handle introduction for application.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure re: redux-persist, but you can do this in a 'splash scene'--basically just an empty view with maybe a background color and/or a logo image-- as your first activity, and using AsyncStorage as:

```
import {AsyncStorage, ...} from 'react-native'
const KEY_SeenStart = 'seenStartKey';

class SplashScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            id: 'splash screen',
            seenStart: 'false',
        };
    }

componentDidMount() {
 AsyncStorage.getItem(KEY_SeenStart).then((seenIntro) => {
    if (seenIntro !== null) {  //has already seen app intro
        this.setState({seenStart: seenIntro});//use this to direct one way or another...
    }else{    //hasn't seen app intro...
        this.setState({seenStart: 'false'});
        try {
            AsyncStorage.setItem(KEY_SeenStart, 'true');//has seen it now, set 'true'
        } catch (error) {
            window.alert('AsyncStorage error: ' + error.message);
        }
    }
});

var whereToGo = (this.state.seenStart == 'true')?'first scene':'app intro';
        this.props.navigator.replace({
            id: whereToGo,
            passProps: {
                ...
                }
        });
  }
...
}
```

The splash scene is also a good place to do any network connections, then you can pass the results as props to your 'first' activity. Hope this helps!